# Show specify element from ICollection<>

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I was interested in how I can get a specific element of the collection. I was looking for documentation on how to do it, but I found nothing about it. I have ICollection and i want show ModelName located in index 3.

**Car class**

```
public class Car{
   public string Brand;
   public string Model;
   public string Engine;
   public string Weight;
}
```

If i create List instead ICollection i want this using:

```
public List<Car> Cars;
string carModel = Cars[3].Model;
```

Comment: The code you posted should work.  What issues are you having?

Comment: The question is unclear - for starters, a List<T> *is* an ICollection<T>. `ICollection<T>` doesn't have an indexer though (that's what IList<T> adds) so you can't use it. Either use an `IList<T>`-derived container, or use IEnumerable's `ElementAt`. This can be expensive though, as the default behaviour is to iterate over the IEnumerable

Comment: I believe the question was how to use `ICollection` rather than `List<>`. But use it in the same manner as the `List<>`. @jdweng

Comment: The OP said "i want show ModelName located in index 3".  So I assumed it wasn't working.  The Title of the Posting and the issue may not be the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The interface [`ICollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1) does not guarantee any consistent order, which is why it does not include any way to access a specific item in the collection by its position.

The [`IList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1) interface implements `ICollection` and is used specifically for lists "that can be individually accessed by index."

So if you are accessing the list as an `ICollection<T>`, you cannot do it. But if you access it as `List<T>` or `IList<T>`, then you can.

```
var list = new List<string> { "zero", "one", "two" };
Console.WriteLine(list[0]); //works

var ilist = (IList) list;
Console.WriteLine(ilist[0]); //works

var collection = (ICollection) list;
Console.WriteLine(collection[0]); //compiler error
```